# Wiered Spring kafka consumer issue. Two consumer with same configuraiton have different behaviour

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

**Currently consumer is working as expected, we are not exactly sure why, as no configuration was changed. Will update the Question once we have more information**

We are deploying a new Kafka pipeline to process data. We have two consumer listening to same topic. One consumer is working as expected and other is not.
The expectation is only new messages should be processed by both listerner. Listner 1 reprocesses all the messages again and again (not expected), while listerner 2 processes only the new messages (Expected). We are not exactly sure why this is happening, as configuration is similar for both Listners, and they are listening to same topic.
Avg processing time for Listner 1= 4-5 seconds.
Avg processing time for Listner 2= 3-4 Seconds.

Kafka consumer factory.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String,Object> consumerFactory(){
        Map<String,Object> configs=new HashMap<>();
        String bootstrap=System.getenv().getOrDefault("BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG","10.99.2.135:9093,10.99.2.136:9093,10.99.2.134:9093");
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrap);
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "60000");
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "60000");
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "20000");
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"latest");
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        //configs.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "update");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configs,new StringDeserializer(),new JsonDeserializer<>(Object.class));
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(5);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(10000);
        return factory;
    }
    
    @Bean
      public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        String bootstrap=System.getenv().getOrDefault("BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG","10.99.2.135:9093,10.99.2.136:9093,10.99.2.134:9093");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,bootstrap);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
      }

      @Bean
      public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerConfigs());
      }
}
```

Listener 1, reprocesses all message after some time.

```
@KafkaListener(groupId="updateCache",topics="omp-orderBuffApi",containerFactory="kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
        public void consume(Object object){
          long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
         logger.info("Start Time of consumer for Details Cache:  {}" ,time);
         ConsumerRecord<String, Object> consumerRecord = (ConsumerRecord<String, Object>) object;
            LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map=(LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) consumerRecord.value();
            logger.info("Payload for Details Cache  : {}" ,map.get("payload"));
            Map<String,Object> payload=(Map<String, Object>) map.get("payload");
            String order = (String) payload.get("ORDERITEMNUMBER");       
            logger.info("OrderItemNumber  :  {}",order);
            long atime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            logger.info("Start Time of api - Details Cache:  {}" ,atime);
            solrController.updateOrderDetailsCache1(payload);
            float atimex = (System.currentTimeMillis() - atime)/1000F;
            logger.info("End Time of api -  Details Cache:  {}" ,atimex);
            float timex = (System.currentTimeMillis() - time)/1000F;
            logger.info("End Time of consumer for Details Cache:  {}" ,timex);
            logger.info("***************************************************");
            countDownLatch0.countDown();
        }
```

Listener 2, working as expected, not reprocessing any message again.

```
@KafkaListener(groupId = "updateSolr", topics = "omp-orderBuffApi", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consumerForSolr(Object object) {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.info("Start Time of consumer for Sorl Details Cache: {}", time);
        ConsumerRecord<String, Object> consumerRecord = (ConsumerRecord<String, Object>) object;
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) consumerRecord.value();
        
        Map<String, Object> payload = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("payload");
         logger.info("payload for Solr Details : {} ", payload);
        String order = (String) payload.get("ORDERITEMNUMBER");
         logger.info("OrderItemNumber Sorl Details Cache: {} ", order);
        long atime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.info("Start Time of api - Solr Details Cache: {}", atime);
        try {
            solrController.updateSolrDate(payload);
        } catch (SolrServerException | IOException | ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        float atimex = (System.currentTimeMillis() - atime) / 1000F;
        logger.info("End Time of api - Solr Details Cache: {}", atimex);
        float timex = (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) / 1000F;
        logger.info("end Time of consumer - Solr Details Cache: {}", timex);
        logger.info("***************************************************");
        countDownLatch3.countDown();
    }
```

Comment: I guess this has something to do with your consumergroups. Can you explicitly clarify which ConsumerGroups (in `ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG`) you are setting for each Listener and also after restarting it?

Comment: okay, thanks. And do the logs say something about any `CommitFailedException`?

Comment: @mike the same config is shared on BOTH consumer groups.configs.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "update"); is definded at bean level, and both consumer group are using same config bean. sorry posted comment twice. will check for the exception in logs once

Comment: The `group.id` is configured on the listener e.g. `groupId = "updateSolr"` and overrides the consumer factory config. Debug logging should help to see what's happening.

Comment: @GaryRussell issue currently is not occurring again, Not entirely sure what made it work properly, we made a couple of changes related to zookeeper and other configs. will update if we find anything new.